# How to find best selling products?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find the best selling products according to this criteria.

Minimum order = 5

- Product A = 100 orders -last order = 29 Dec 2021
- Product B = 6 orders - last order = 1 Jan 2022
- Product C = 3 Orders - last order = 3 Jan 2022

Product B must show first.

Product C will not show because it has less than 5 orders.

Here is my database structure and what I tried

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04e2a92/23

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You forgot to type the SQL statement (into the fiddle) that you tried....

Comment: Here is what i tried.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04e2a92/23

Comment: A SO question is supposed to be self-contained, i.e. contain both sample table data _and the expected result_, i.e. [mcve]. (The sqlfiddle is great ,though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the query for getting all products with minimum order count of 5, sorted in descending order.

```
SELECT p_name, 
    tmp.total_orders, 
    tmp.last_purchased
FROM products P
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT product_id, 
    COUNT(*) AS total_orders, 
    MAX(created_at) AS last_purchased
  FROM order_items
  GROUP BY product_id
  HAVING total_orders >= 5
) AS tmp ON tmp.product_id = P.id
ORDER BY last_purchased DESC
```

Comment: I think you should/can change the query to be more efficient. See second query in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04e2a92/46  (It is using a `HAVING` and the `ORDER BY` is done at the correct place )  (Because an `ORDER BY` in a sub-query, without `LIMIT` is useless....)

Comment: @Luuk sorting should be on date. latest order product must show first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and comments. I have updated my query.

Comment: @OwaisKiani: If you want to sort on anything else than give in my answer, then you can change the `ORDER BY`.